# Regex for remove everything after "_" in all anchor Tag

Tags: regex, string, notepad++

I want any regex to remove everything after underscore in all anchor Tag e.g

input:  `<a href="/category_592">Text</a>`

Output  `<a href="/category">Text</a>`

Comment: This problem is not a good fit for regex.  Have you considered parsing the text as HTML instead and then altering the value of all `a` tags' `href` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you should avoid parsing HTML with regex, but since this is a case of anchor tag which won't be nested, hence you can do a quick work using regex. Use this regex to match the data in group1 and group2,

```
(<a\s+[^>]*?href=["'][^']*?)_.*?(["'])
```

and replace it with `\1\2` (or `$1$2` as per the language)

[Check the demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ygeAc/2/)

You haven't mentioned how should the data be replaced in case there are multiple underscores in the href attribute, so for now I have done it in a way where it replaces everything from first occurrence of underscore but you can easily do it for last occurrence of underscore by making the regex as greedy.

Comment: Thank you very much @pushpesh but this regex work but only first anchor tag, not every one.

Comment: @engg.Furqan: Updated the regex and now it will match with any number of tags. Let me know if you further have any queries.

Comment: Really thanks @pushpesh now solved.

Comment: Happy to help Furqan :)

Comment: Appreciated <3 @pushpesh now I am trying to make regex  change uppercase to lowercase in anchor tag like input `<a href="/CategoRy_592">Text</a>` Output `<a href="/category_592">Text</a>` I am trying  find `<a(\w*)</a> replase ` to `\l$1` can you help me to rectify this. Thanks in advanse

Comment: @engg.Furqan: You need to use `\L$1` (capital L) instead of \l$1

Comment: I am trying to use this `<a(\w*)</a>` but got pattern error due to ( / ) forward slash

Comment: You need to escape `/` with `\/` so make your regex `<a(\w*)<\/a>`

Comment: I already try this `<a(\w*)<\/a>` replace with `\L$1` but the expression does not match the subject string.

Comment: Hey @pushpesh can you help me to make this expression I am trying to change lowercase to uppercase in anchor tag but not get exact regex I have use `<a(\w*)<\/a>` to `\L$1`